# $invalid not working in ng-if condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-form

In Angular 1.5, I have the following setup:

```
<form name="linksForm">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Region</label>
    <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.user.region">
      <md-option ng-repeat="region in $ctrl.allRegions" value="{{region.id}}" ng-bind="region.name"></md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container ng-if="$ctrl.user.region">
    <label>Territory</label>
    <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.user.territory" name="territory" required>
      <md-option ng-repeat="territory in $ctrl.getTerritories($ctrl.user.region)" value="{{territory.id}}" ng-bind="territory.name"></md-option>
    </md-select> 
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container ng-if="linksForm.territory.$valid">
    <label>House</label>
    <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.user.house">
      <md-option ng-repeat="house in $ctrl.allHouses" value="{{house.id}}" ng-bind="house.name"></md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</form>
```

Here is the logic:

1. At first, only the regions list is visible.
2. When a region is selected, the territory list appears with a list of territories from the selected region.
3. When a territory is selected, the house list appears.

So far, so good. The thing works. The only problem is when I change the region, here is what happens:

1. The territory list changes, and since ngModel cannot match any of the new options, the territory selector is now unset. This is working as expected, *but...*
2. **The house list does not disappear**, despite the `territory` selector being required, therefore the territory field should be invalid.

Comment: put `<pre>{{linksForm|json}}</pre>` in view to help see validation object. Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: also suggest assigning form name to controller and use that

Comment: Does `linksForm.territory.$valid` equal to false afterwards? Did you try to insert a `$ctrl.user.region` value inside (wouldn't work for false values, but might be helpful)?